# the result doesn't appear in listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

May I know what's wrong with my code below.. 'cause it doesn't show the result. I want to view the name of employees, their number of activities per month, then their average grade by dividing the num. of activities to their score. I hope you can help me to do this. I want to view it on list box

the format is this:

```
Juan Dela Cruz
Count: 10    
Score: 5
Grade: 2

econ = new SqlConnection();
econ.ConnectionString = emp_con;
econ.Open();
int found = -1;
string Log_User, Count, Score;
int iGrade = 0;
string n = "";
string strScore = "Score: ";
string strGrade = "Grade: ";
string strCount = "Count: ";
ecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Log_User, Count = COUNT(Det_Score), Score = SUM(Det_Score) FROM MEMBER M,DETAILS D WHERE D.Emp_Id = M.Emp_Id AND Month(Sched_Start) like" + "'" + comMonth.Text + "'AND Year(Sched_Start) like" + "'" + txtYear.Text + "'GROUP BY Log_User", econ);
ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
ecmd.Connection = econ;
dr = ecmd.ExecuteReader();
listBox1.Text = txtYear.Text;
listBox1.Text = comMonth.Text;
while (dr.Read())
{
 Log_User = (string)dr["Log_User"];
 Count = (string)dr["Count"];
 Score = (string)dr["Score"];
 iGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Count) / Convert.ToInt32(Score);
 found += 1;
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(n));
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(strGrade) + Convert.ToString(iGrade));
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(strScore) + Convert.ToString(Score));
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(strCount) + Convert.ToString(Count));
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(Log_User));
 listBox1.Items.Insert(found, Convert.ToString(n));
}

econ.Close();
}
catch (Exception x)
{
  MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Connection Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I want to view the result here but I can't see the output. Is there any problem in my sql statement?? In MS SQL 2005 when I run the sql, it run smoothly but when I run it to VS 2010, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Please don't throw "C#" at the end of your titles. That's what tags for for.

Comment: Sorry.. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?? thanks..

Comment: No. That's much too much code to read. Create a small example that reproduces the problem, then post the example.

Comment: After you figure this problem out, you might want to  throw the code over on StackExchange code review... you have a bunch of improperly disposed of resources that you need to deal with. The econ.Close() isn't nearly enough to keep you out of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Text = "";
econ = new SqlConnection();
econ.ConnectionString = emp_con;
econ.Open();
float iGrade = 0;
float Grade = 0.00F;
string Log_User;
float Count, Score;
string n = "";
string strScore = "Score: ";
string strGrade = "Grade: ";
string strCount = "Count: ";
string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
ecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Log_User, Count = COUNT(Det_Score), Score = SUM(Det_Score) FROM MEMBER M,DETAILS D WHERE D.Emp_Id = M.Emp_Id AND Log_User like" + "'" + Convert.ToString(comEmployee.Text) + "'AND Month(Sched_Start) =" + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(iMonth) + "'AND Year(Sched_Start) =" + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text) + "'GROUP BY Log_User", econ);
ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
ecmd.Connection = econ;
dr = ecmd.ExecuteReader();
listBox1.Items.Add("As of " + date + ": "+ comMonth.Text + ", "+ txtYear.Text);
while (dr.Read())
{
   if (dr == null || !dr.HasRows)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("No record found.", "Error");
   }
   else
   {
      Log_User = (string)dr["Log_User"];
      Count = (dr["Count"] as int?) ?? 0;
      Score = (dr["Score"] as int?) ?? 0;
      try
      {
         iGrade = Score / Count;
         Grade = iGrade * 100;
      }
      catch (DivideByZeroException)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception occured");
      }
      listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(n));
      listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Log_User));
      listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(strCount + Count));
      listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(strScore + Score));
      listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(strGrade + Grade));
      }
   }               
   econ.Close();
```

the code above is my answer for my question..I hope it can help others. Thanks to those people who helped me to figured it out.. :D God bless

Answer (score 0):

Can be a couple of problem.

Did u try running the sql statement in Sql Management Studio?

Did they have any results?

If so, try use

`listbox1.Items.Add` instead of `Insert`

No exception error, rite?

If I were you, I'd use `sqlDataAdapter` and put all results into `datatable` then I would check whether the `datatable` has any rows. If so, I will loop and add them into listbox.

Comment: At the very least, set a breakpoint at the first Insert statement, then view the listbox object in the Locals windows (or just hover over it), and see if the value has been set. My guess is, it's not being set at all. Like William said, use Add, not Insert. As well, putting the data into a datatable makes it easier to look at and debug.

Comment: I tried it to my SQL Management Studio, and it runs smoothly. but in VS 2010 it doesn't run. I tried your listbox1.Items.Add it shows red line. i will try SQLDataAdapter, and post the result here.

Comment: Use Fischermaen's method for `listbox1.Items.Add` to get show correctly.. if that still has the problem. Create a temporary `listItem` first. Then fill the `listItem.Value` and `listItem.Text` After that `listbox1.Items.Add(listItem)`

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code in a way it should work:

```
econ = new SqlConnection(); 
econ.ConnectionString = emp_con; 
econ.Open(); 
string Log_User, Count, Score; 
int iGrade = 0; 
string n = ""; 
string strScore = "Score: "; 
string strGrade = "Grade: "; 
string strCount = "Count: "; 
ecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Log_User, Count = COUNT(Det_Score), Score = SUM(Det_Score) FROM MEMBER M,DETAILS D WHERE D.Emp_Id = M.Emp_Id AND Month(Sched_Start) like" + "'" + comMonth.Text + "'AND Year(Sched_Start) like" + "'" + txtYear.Text + "'GROUP BY Log_User", econ); 
ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
ecmd.Connection = econ; 
dr = ecmd.ExecuteReader(); 
listBox1.Items.Add(txtYear.Text); 
listBox1.Items.Add(comMonth.Text); 
while (dr.Read()) 
{ 
 Log_User = (string)dr["Log_User"]; 
 Count = (string)dr["Count"]; 
 Score = (string)dr["Score"]; 
 iGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Count) / Convert.ToInt32(Score); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}", n)); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Grade: {0}", iGrade))); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Score: {0}",  Score))); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Count: {0}", Count)); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(Log_User); 
 listBox1.Items.Add(n.ToString()); 
} 

econ.Close(); 
} 
catch (Exception x) 
{ 
  MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Connection Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK,     MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
```

Comment: @Kevzz: Then debug the code, there must be an error in `while (dr.Read())`.

Comment: thanks for the code.. I'm trying to debug my codes.. as of now, The results are showing but their still some codes of mine that I need to change.. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue is going to be your SQL statement, specifically the likes. You don't add the %, so unless that is typed in by the user, you won't get any results.

Also, I don't think that like is appropriate in that context since you are looking for a month number.

Finally, you should use parameters to prevent SQL injection, but I'll leave that as another exercise.

Here is the minimum change you need:

```
ecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Log_User, Count = COUNT(Det_Score), Score = SUM(Det_Score) FROM MEMBER M,DETAILS D WHERE D.Emp_Id = M.Emp_Id AND Month(Sched_Start) = " + comMonth.Text + " AND Year(Sched_Start) = " + txtYear.Text + " GROUP BY Log_User", econ);
```

Also, you don't need to use insert on the list items, you should use add instead:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(n));
etc...
```

And finally, you should cast the values from the database in case they contain DBNulls:

```
Log_User = dr["Log_User"] as string;
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Insert to Add.

```
 if (dr == null || !dr.HasRows) {
                                 //No records found
                                }
     else
       {
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(n));
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(strGrade) + Convert.ToString(iGrade));
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(strScore) + Convert.ToString(Score));
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(strCount) + Convert.ToString(Count));
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(Log_User));
     listBox1.Items.Add(found, Convert.ToString(n));
      }
```

Regards

Comment: Just delete the found in the parenthesis, then it will run.. thanks for helping me. :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that SQL query runs correctly in SQL Mgmt studio? You're not grouping on the Count field (at the very least), so you should get an aggregate error.

Also, you might want to a proper join, and not join via a WHERE clause (personal preference).

Actually, your SQL Statement seems broken. Try this:

```
SELECT Log_User, COUNT(Det_Score) as count, SUM(Det_Score) as Score
FROM MEMBER M
    JOIN DETAILS D on M.Emp_Id = D.Emp_Id
WHERE MONTH(Sched_Start) like + "' + comMonth.Text + '" AND YEAR(Sched_Start) LIKE "' + txtYear.Text '"
GROUP BY Log_User, COUNT(Det_Score) as count, SUM(Det_Score) as Score
```